# Wx Maxima output format

Tags: notation, maxima-software

What do the thick solid vertical bars just outside the parentheses represent. See the screen grab of a wx maxima output

[image: Screen grab of wxmaxima output]

See also here, the input and output.:

[image: Screen grab 2]

note: this only occurs sometimes. Other times the bars do not appear. Are they just redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those "bars" are actually the crossing ends of large upper- and lower-half-parentheses. As such, they are not significant, they just mean maxima is not trying to be too clever with fonts and typesetting.